# Encountered during contract execution [Reverted]

Tags: etherscan, error

When trying to sent some ETH from myetherwallet getting followinf error:

```
 Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Reverted]
```

transaction links:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xad2aacfeb5c23d192b9f4bd5e9b402962012c61f0bc16a3a9902e10dd4ea8675
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x241ba9fc1fc75a87afe70767b99276a1fa4ea72c1da6a6b4eb155d2800d6a251

contract code - https://etherscan.io/address/0x37d82a4e03e93529c1a32429984e12e7875ea1d8#code

It this due to issue in code ?

Comment: can helme...?
0xb75b371f2bc41f86e4df29bb616771d2d56d4acd8fc202f1120623145dadedea

Answer (score 2):

In both transactions, your input data is empty and you are sending an amount of Ether to the contract. Because you are not calling a specific function, you will be calling the ["fallback function"](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html?highlight=fallback%20function#fallback-function) in the contract. That function is defined as:

```
// ---------
// Dont accept ETH;
// ---------
function () public payable { 
    revert();
}
```

Note that the function specifically denies a user sending Ether to the contract, causing the problem you are seeing. Thus, the error is by design, not a problem with the code.